# Update table with a sequence of values

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I'm looking for a way to update an existing table with an ascending sequence of dates. Using this select works:

```
SELECT
    TO_DATE('01-MAR-15') + (rownum * 2)
FROM all_tables
WHERE rownum <= 35
```

I cannot, however, use this in an update query. In Oracle, how could I write an update table statement similar to this?

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_date_column = (
    TO_DATE('01-MAR-15') + (rownum * 2)
)
WHERE my_keys IN (
    // my subquery here - select my_key from my_table where....
)
```

Comment: so you're trying to do this in SQL server?

Comment: @xQbert I tagged the question as Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statement, like here:

```
merge into my_table m
using (
  select my_key, date '2015-03-01' + (rownum * 2) dt
    from my_table where my_key in (1, 3)) u
on (m.my_key = u.my_key)
when matched then update set my_date_column = u.dt;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/084e5f/1)

Place your subquery in `using` clause. `My_key` has to be unique.